# How to properly change the name of a Blazor component (razor file)

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a problem I´m a little irritated with:
Let´s say I have a Blazor component `MyCustomComponent.razor` which is located at `ProjectName.Client.Shared`.
Now I can use it in my code like this:

`<MyCustomComponent></MyCustomComponent>`.

But as soon as I rename that component via right click on `MyCustomComponent.razor` to for example `MyFirstCustomComponent.razor`, still only the old component name appears in IntelliSense and the new one doesn´t get recognized. This error message appears:

> Found markup element with unexpected name 'MyFirstCustomComponent.razor'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.

Even if I do a full rebuild, nothing happens.

My current solution is to delete the old component and to create a new component with the new name, but that´s not really a good way to do this in my opinion.

Is there a place where I also have to change the old name to the new name in some other file? I couldn´t find any appearance of the old component name in my code after renaming, but it was still somehow there to select from IntelliSense...

Comment: You have two choices. Put @namespace ProjectName in the component, or add a using  to _imports.razor. I also have to unload / reload the project sometimes for IntelliSense to pick up the changes if I rename a .razor file.

Comment: I have the same problem. For me I have the using statement in _imports.razor, I have tried to add the import in the same file, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Intellisense database is corrupted. The easiest thing to do is to rebuild it.

This is what I do:

1. Close solution and exit Visual Studio
2. Delete the *.suo file in the .vs folder
3. Restart Visual Studio and reopen solution

The Intellisense database will be rebuilt.

Comment: But doing this every time after renaming a razor file is also not really convenient.

Answer (score 1):

My visual studio does this as well, however usually after closing all the affected files from the editing window intellisense catches up. Sometimes it takes a few minutes, I just carry on working till it clears. Maybe try rebuilding the cache, which will then make it act 'normal' going forward?